# Validating decimal pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I use the following pattern for decimal validation.

```
var pattern = /^([0-9]+)[.][0-9]{0,2}$/;
```

I need to enter only 10 digits.
for example,

```
12345678.00
```

need to enter 8 digits before the dot.
after dot,the 2 digits are optional. how to validate only enter 8 digits before dot symbol?

Comment: I know I already submitted an answer but I have a question that might cause me to edit it. What if the user enters 3 or 4 digits after the dot, do you want to match the first two or not?

Comment: Shouldn't the dot itself be optional as well? With at least 1 digit required after it, if it's present?

Comment: @JustinMorgan Although I upvoted your comment for pointing out the optional decimal point depending on whether or not there are digits after it, if you think about it, having a lone decimal point technically does not invalidate the entry as a valid number, if OP chooses to build his/her application this way.

Comment: @Nasser - Yeah, I think you could make good arguments for both allowing and disallowing the orphan decimal point. Personally, I'd call it invalid, but that's me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this!

```
^[\d]{1,8}([\.|\,]\d{1,2})?$
```

Regards..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/^[0-9]{8}[.][0-9]{0,2}\b/g
```

Basically means "exactly 8 digits before the dot, and up to 2 digits after the dot". Also, if you want some regexp shorthand, you can use `\d` which escapes digits

```
/^\d{8}[.]\d{0,2}\b/g
```

Also, this was not clear in your question: do you want to match the two digits after the decimal if the user enters 3 or more characters? If yes, then remove the `\b` part and it will work for you

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
/^[0-9]{8}[.]([0-9]{2})?$/
```

This should make sure you have 8 digits before the dot, and exactly 0 or 2 digits after the dot.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you *really* want is this:

```
/^[0-9]{8}(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/
```

You can also write it like this:

```
/^\d{8}(\.\d\d?)?$/
```

This pattern makes the dot optional, and if it's present, requires either one or two digits after it. The `\d` is shorthand for `[0-9]` (they're not identical in all regex flavors, but they are in JavaScript).

As you've written it, your pattern requires the decimal point, even if there are no decimal digits. So `12345678` will fail, while `12354678.` will pass. That's probably not what you want; in fact, I doubt you'd consider the second number valid.